# What is the target release date for version 2.3.3 of the javalite package on Maven Central?

Tags: javalite

I was wondering if there was a known or targeted release date for version 2.3.3 of the javalite and javalite-common packages, and specifically release to Maven Central.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This  is a perfect time asking this question. The release 2.4-j8 is in progress now, and will be available on Maven Central shortly.
The release notes are here: https://github.com/javalite/javalite/releases, but the Releases page, JavaDoc and the blog will be updated later this week.

Here are some of the big things:

- https://javalite.io/validations
- https://javalite.io/processing_web_requests_implicit_conversion
- https://javalite.io/processing_web_requests_with_validation

There is a number of other smaller  features and bugs there.

The version number dropped one number, with a previous release  moving from 2.3.2-j8 to 2.4-j8.

Track the  site for a blog  later this week: https://javalite.io/blog

This release is for Java 8 only.

Comment: Thanks Igor!  I was wondering if the dom4j dependency would bump from 2.1.1 to 2.1.3 in this release?  In the source for the release, it looks it is still on 2.1.1.

Comment: @Code1, we do upgrade dependencies from time to time. I think you can safely exclude the 2.1.1 and bring 2.1.3. I will create a new issue to upgrade dependencies

Comment: thanks - one final note regarding 2.1.1, there is an open CVE for this version, https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2020-10683.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Code1, thanks for a suggestion: https://github.com/javalite/javalite/issues/1054 this wil make it to the next release

Comment: Great @ipolevoy.  Thank you!